# Google Analytics activevisitors error php (real-time)

Tags: php, google-analytics, real-time

I'm trying to create a php page that displays the number of visitors and pages views for the day so far, along with the current number of active users.  I have got the visitors and page views to work without any issues.  However, for the activeVisitors call, I'm getting the following error.

```
Fatal Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object
```

Are the real time APIs still locked down to users who are whitelisted?

Below is the code I currently have

```
$client->setAccessType('offline_access');
$analytics = new Google_AnalyticsService($client);
$analytics_id   = 'ga:XXXXXXXX';
$lastWeek       = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 week'));
$today          = date('Y-m-d');

try {
    $results = $analytics->data_ga->get($analytics_id,
                        $today,
                        $today,'ga:visitors');
    echo '<b>Number of visits today:</b> ';
    $visits = $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:visitors'];
    echo $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:visitors'];
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'There was an error : - ' . $e->getMessage();
}


try {
    $results = $analytics->data_ga->get($analytics_id,
                        $today,
                        $today,'ga:pageviews');
    echo '<br/><b>Number of page views today:</b> ';
    $pageviews = $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:pageviews'];
    echo $pageviews;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'There was an error : - ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Above works. 
And then the attempt at the real-time data which fails.

```
$optParams = array(
    'dimensions' => 'ga:medium');

try {
    $results = $analytics->data_realtime->get(
      'ga:XXXXXXX',
      'ga:activeVisitors',
      $optParams);

    echo '<br/><b>Number of active users:</b> ';
    $active = $results['totalsForAllResults']['ga:activeVisitors'];
    echo $active;
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo 'There was an error : - ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I thought maybe I was just incorrectly calling the actual value, but the error code is directing straight to the get line.

Answer (score 0):

The Google_AnalyticsService.php file has been updated since the most recent stable release, so the code that I linked to wasn't actually loaded in my project. I resolved this by updating my library to include the code displayed on their [website](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/Google_AnalyticsService.php#31). Once I included these files the above code worked without any issues.